# Can I use the .Net CF unhandled exception dialog to display and exception that was caught?

Tags: .net, exception, compact-framework

In my .Net 3.5 Compact Framework app I recently added an unhandled exception handler.  I did it just so I could add the error to our log file and reboot the system.  In certain modes I want to display the error to the user. I find that the messagebox is far inferior for error display than the dialog the CLR would use if I didn't catch the exception.

Is there any way I can get to that dialog and show it to the user or is it private and hidden deep in the CLR?

Comment: I think it is bad idea to process *handled* exceptions as an *unhandled* one.

Comment: It is effectively an unhandled exception.  It wasn't handled in the code, all I'm doing is logging it and showing it to the user if it's a debug build.  Either way the program is ending.  

Can you clarify what is bad about doing this?  I know it's bad to catch unhandled exceptions and then let the program keep running since it would be in an unknown state but that's not what I'm doing.

Comment: how to did you capture the un-handled exceptions? I'm in need of this piece of code. Can you please help me?

Comment: I just wired it up before calling Application.Run().  Like this: 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);

Answer (score 0):

We wrote our own dialog for this case. The user can expand a hidden TextBox with additional information such as the StackTrace etc.

In my opinion the out-of-the-box MessageBox on WindowsCE and Windows Mobile is not usable in most cases.